# Copy timestamp value fails from one column to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two timestamp fields formed with -

```
CREATE TABLE `test` 
(`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`first_date` TIMESTAMP NULL , 
`second_date` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I inserted two rows using

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `first_date`, `second_date`) 
VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2017-10-18 17:02:14'), (NULL, NULL, '2017-10-18 17:02:14');
```

Now, I need to copy the second date value to the first date column, but when I try the update query both the date value get updated to today's date.

```
update test set first_date = second_date where id=<row_id>

id | first_date          | second_date
----------------------------------------------
3  | 2017-11-17 16:09:03 | 2017-11-17 16:09:29 --> This value was 
4  | NULL                | 2017-10-18 17:02:14     "2017-10-18 17:02:14" 
5  | NULL                | 2017-10-18 17:02:14      before the update query.
```

Somehow, the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` attribute of the second_date  is creating a problem here. How would I copy the value from second column without affecting the existing value of `second_date`?

Comment: I can remove the attribute and execute the update query and reassign the attribute again. Is there any other way to proceed?

Comment: Create another table with id and second date values. Use that as inputs to an update query. But second date will get updated. (OR modify the table to temporarily remove the on update condition ... not my preferred optio n)

Comment: I'm curious, why expect it not to change? It's specifically set up to do so *on update*!? But it seems, if you'd just include the `second_date` in the update, you'll get what you need. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/crg1DF4qn7wF5VKqu5Zy6R/0   (not sure though if this is standard behavior)

Comment: Thanks, Yoshi. working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should help you to copy the value from second column without affecting the existing value of second_date:

```
UPDATE test SET first_date = second_date , second_date = second_date WHERE  id=<row_id>
```